# How to I add space in data-bind"text:..."?

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js

I'm trying to add space between file names in a div.
It looks like this

```
<span class="upload-bar__file-name" data-bind="text: name"></span>
```

I tried this but didn't work

```
<span class="upload-bar__file-name" data-bind="text: ' ' + name"></span>
```

EDIT:
I'm trying to accomplish this :

if there are 3 names: **A B** and **C**, I want it to be displayed like this : **A B C** and not like this : **ABC**

Comment: @JaromandaX if there are 3 names: A B and C, I want it to be displayed like this : A B C and not like this : ABC

Comment: If I try and type 'data-bind="text: ' 123' + name',  I will get 123A123B123C. I figured that I would be able to display space instead of '123'

Comment: I see now, this is `knockout.js` - sorry for my absent minded comments

Comment: does `data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + name"` work?

Comment: or even `<span class="upload-bar__file-name" data-bind="text: name"></span>&nbsp;` ... spitballing here

Comment: @JaromandaX It worked. Tried data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + name and did the job. Thanks. You can write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<span class="upload-bar__file-name" data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + name"></span>
```

to add a so-called "non-breaking space" to the `name`